# Asimbench benchmark running in gem5 fails with "fatal: Unable to find destination for [0x40008000:0x40008040] on system.iobus"

Tags: benchmarking, gem5, moby

I have downloaded asimbench files which provided in the gem5.org website and I have modified the config/common/FSConfig.py with following changes:

```
def makeArmSystem(..)

..................

self.cf0 = CowIdeDisk(driveID='master')

self.cf2 = CowIdeDisk(driveID='master')

self.cf0.childImage(mdesc.disk())

self.cf2.childImage(disk("sdcard-1g-mxplayer.img"))


#Old platforms have a built-in IDE or CF controller. Default to

#the IDE controller if both exist. New platforms expect the

#storage controller to be added from the config script.

if hasattr(self.realview, "ide"):

#self.realview.ide.disks = [self.cf0]

self.realview.ide.disks = [self.cf0, self.cf2]

elif hasattr(self.realview, "cf_ctrl"):

#self.realview.cf_ctrl.disks = [self.cf0]

self.realview.cf_ctrl.disks = [self.cf0, self.cf2]
else:
self.pci_ide = IdeController(disks=[self.cf0])

pci_devices.append(self.pci_ide
```

I used this command:

```
 ./build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --mem-size=8192MB
   --disk-image=/home/yaz/gem5/full_system_images/disks/ARMv7a-ICS-Android.SMP.Asimbench-v3.img
   --kernel=/home/yaz/gem5/full_system_images/binaries/vmlinux.smp.ics.arm.asimbench.2.6.35
   --os-type=android-ics  --cpu-type=MinorCPU  --machine-type=VExpress_GEM5  --script=/home/yaz/gem5/full_system_images/boot/adobe.rcS
```

> warn: CheckedInt already exists in allParams. This may be caused by
> the Python 2.7 compatibility layer. warn: Enum already exists in
> allParams. This may be caused by the Python 2.7 compatibility layer.
> warn: ScopedEnum already exists in allParams. This may be caused by
> the Python 2.7 compatibility layer. gem5 Simulator System.
> http://gem5.org gem5 is copyrighted software; use the --copyright
> option for details. gem5 version 20.0.0.3 gem5 compiled Jul 7 2020
> 16:17:12 gem5 started Jul 16 2020 04:41:50 gem5 executing on
> yazeed-OptiPlex-9010, pid 3367 command line: ./build/ARM/gem5.opt
> configs/example/fs.py --mem-size=8192MB
> --disk-image=/home/yaz/gem5/full_system_images/disks/ARMv7a-ICS-Android.SMP.Asimbench-v3.img
> --kernel=/home/yaz/gem5/full_system_images/binaries/vmlinux.smp.ics.arm.asimbench.2.6.35
> --os-type=android-ics --cpu-type=MinorCPU --machine-type=VExpress_GEM5 --script=/home/yaz/gem5/full_system_images/boot/adobe.rcS
> Global frequency set at 1000000000000 ticks per second
> warn: No dot file generated. Please install pydot to generate the dot file and pdf.
> info: kernel located at: /home/yaz/gem5/full_system_images/binaries/vmlinux.smp.ics.arm.asimbench.2.6.35
> system.vncserver: Listening for connections on port 5900
> system.terminal: Listening for connections on port 3456
> system.realview.uart1.device: Listening for connections on port 3457
> system.realview.uart2.device: Listening for connections on port 3458
> system.realview.uart3.device: Listening for connections on port 3459
> 0: system.remote_gdb: listening for remote gdb on port 7000 info:
> Using bootloader at address 0x80000000
> info: Using kernel entry physical address at 0x140008000 warn: DTB file specified, but no
> device tree support in kernel
> **** REAL SIMULATION ****
> warn:Existing EnergyCtrl, but no enabled DVFSHandler found. info: Entering
> event queue @ 0. Starting simulation...
>
> fatal: Unable to find destination for [0x40008000:0x40008040] on system.iobus
> Memory Usage: 8786764 KBytes

Thanks for helping

Comment: Please format your code properly. With python, one can never be certain where your function body starts and ends unless you provide proper indentation

Comment: There was an error with a similar message at: https://gem5.atlassian.net/browse/GEM5-658 can you check if that commit fixes it? Otherwise please also open a new JIra ticket for it.